# Unix List Files After Modified Date of a File

Tags: list, unix, search

I know I can use `ls -ltr` to list files in time order, but is there a way to execute a command to only list the files created after the creation date of another file (let's call it `acknowledge.tmp`)?

I assume that the command will look something like this:

```
ls -1 /path/to/directory | ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-newer` option to the `find` command:

> ```
>  -newer file         True if the current file has been  modi-
>                      fied  more  recently  than  the argument
>                      file.
> ```

So your command would be

```
find /path/to/directory -newer acknowledge.tmp
```

However, this will descend into, and return results from, sub-directories